# How Okhttp change the rule of the cache key set

Tags: okhttp

okhttp,the cache key is the url.But every time I request the same url I need to put param of "distinctRequestId" to distinguish every request.It lead to my url is different every time.But the content is the same .So I want to set the cache key custom. which i can get the cache is Unique.Thx